# Is it possible to use multiple methods depending on the status in onResume methods android

Tags: java, android, textview, activity-lifecycle

I have 3 types status of so that my app will update these status in a `TextView` depending on the status

So here they are working fine when I run the application

But when minimise and maximise the app these status are not updating I am confused I what way I can show them in `onResume()`

Hence my 3 statements are in `void` I cant use `returns`

these are my status

```
@Override
public void onVLoading() {
    mtc.post(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mtc.setText("Buffering");
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onVStarted() {
    mtc.post(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mtc.setText("Playing");
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onVStopped() {
    mtc.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mtc.setText("Passed");
        }
    });
}
```

So I want to show them at onResume in android

this is my `onResume()` method

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mVMG.connect();
    /*onVLoading()
      onVStarted()
      onVStopped()*/
    }
```

Actually I want to show show these text-view status at `onResume()`

is there any suggestion on this kind please help..

Answer (score 1):

Just create a function for showing the status.

```
private void showStatus(){
   mtc.setText(statusText);
}
```

and update the statusText variable. Make statusText variable as global static variable.

```
@Override
public void onVLoading() {
    mtc.post(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            statusText = "Buffering";
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onVStarted() {
    mtc.post(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            statusText ="Playing";
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onVStopped() {
    mtc.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            statusText = "Passed";
        }
    });
}



@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        showStatus();
        mVMG.connect();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ciril.. Here I have Given statusText as `String statusText;`But even Now also its not coming at onResume ... Please Help me Every thing is playing but Just this status is not updating

Comment: I Have Given like `showStatus();` `mtc.setText(statusText);` but not working at on reume